# How to test anonymous local functions with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, tooltipster

I have the following construct inside the link function of a directive in my Angular code (the tooltipster library can be found under http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/):

```
scope.$on(MY_EVENTS.DATA_RETRIEVED, function(event) {
    $timeout(function() {
        var badge = element.find('.tooltip-hook');

        badge.tooltipster({
            content: $('Default tooltip'),
            contentAsHtml: true,
            theme: 'tooltipster-light',
            functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltipster) {
                continueTooltipster();

                origin.tooltipster('content', scope.getTooltip());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem that I have is that when I test this code with Jasmine the coverage reporter complains because the function passed as `functionBefore` is not covered by my tests.

How can I unit test with Jasmine whether this function is being called before the tooltip is shown (which is technically not testing my code but the tooltipster code) and (and this is about my code) also that the statements inside of the function are executed? To test the latter I would have to get a hold of spies on the parameters of an already anonymous and local function.

I know I can simulate a mouseenter event with the jasmine-jquery plugin which should provoke the tooltip to show up, but how can I cover the `functionBefore` with a Jasmine unit test?

Comment: So if you simulate the mouseenter successfully the functionBefore isn't hit? That doesn't make too much sense if the popup is being activated.

Comment: You don't need jquery with angular. You can use angular native functions (their limited jquery implementation) to simulate an event

Comment: Can't you just define that function outside of the event and set the functionBefore equal to that function? Then you can test the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make sense to test whether `tooltipster` calls that code or not. As you say, it doesn't make sense to test that frameworks work correctly. The frameworks have (or should have) their own tests.

However, what you can test is that the function you are passing to `tooltipster` does what you want.

For example, you could convert the `tooltipster` function into a `spy`:

```
var badge = ...
var passedObject;

//we are using a spy to get the object that is being passed to tooltipster
spyOn(badge, 'tooltipster').andCallFake(function (obj) {
   passedObject = obj;
});

//TODO: wait for the $timeout function to be executed

var origin = jasmine.createSpyObj(...);
var continueTooltipster = jasmine.createSpy('continueTooltipster');

//now let's just test the function
passedObject.functionBefore(origin, continueTooltipster);
expect(continueTooltipster).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This will work but in this case I believe it's not something you should test. Note that you should test things that are meaningful, it doesn't make sense to test everything just to get 100% coverage.